# CSS in IE8 not working

Tags: css, animation, menu, internet-explorer-8

This is doing my head in, please can someone help? I have made a site, works in Ie9 + 10 and all other browsers, but the animated menu doesnt work in IE8 and there are people using that to view the site..

here is the css:

```
.menu, .menu ul, .menu li, .menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.menu {
    height: 40px;
    width: 800px;
    background: #f7d000;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7d000 0%,#f7d000 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7d000 0%,#f7d000100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7d000 0%,#f7d000 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7d000 0%,#f7d000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #f7d000 0%,#f7d000 100%);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
}

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:first-child a {
    border-left: none;
}

.menu li:last-child a {
    border-right: none;
}

.menu li:hover > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    background: #f7d000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}

.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f7d000;
}

.menu ul li:last-child a {
    border: none;
}
```

The site is: www.softwaretestingawards.com any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To be honest, if the site functions in IE8, without the fancy animations, that should be enough. If the browser doesn't naturally support something, we shouldn't be expected to force it to do it, just because some users are too lazy to use the best versions of their browsers.

Comment: I cleaned your code for you , i presume you dont actually have `<br>`s in your css file.

Comment: Can you put this up oh jsfiddle.net?

Comment: To get animations to work in IE8 you need to use jQuery, IE8 does not use CSS3

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks +1 for you, though IE8 is the latest IE one can get in XP.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks also coorporate companies dont want to update "x" thousand machines. its an IT nightmare

Comment: @gaynorvader    here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/avamonroe/8jtnT/

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks I hear you trust me. IE is the devil, yet 37% of our site visitors are on IE, and 11% of those use IE 8

Answer (score 3):

IE8 does not support CSS3 animations.

See this reference:
http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20tran

---

You many want to consider using javascript animations, like `jQuery.animate`

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: yeah the <br>s are just to display here

Comment: @avamonroe no need for them, SO handles new lines nicely.

Comment: @avamonroe all I did was removed the `<br>`s. IE8 doesnt support CSS3 what more do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't work in Internet Explorer 8 is because it does not support CSS3 animations. I recommend you make a script to detect if Internet Explorer 8 is being used and, if it is, dynamically change the website so it doesn't have the fancy CSS3 animations.

Answer (score 0):

to make work the css in IE8 you can try using PIE.htc, refere this site for solution and demos if you want  http://css3pie.com/demos/, actually it worked for me :)